# Audio Codec2 on STM32

Tags: audio, embedded, stm32, codec

I wanted to use **[Codec2](https://www.rowetel.com/wordpress/?page_id=452)** on **STM32F4xx**, so I took the existing libraries and ran them on the hardware - a Nucleo board. Then I started measuring the time it takes to encode and decode one frame - a block of sound signal lasting 40 ms, which corresponds to 320 samples at an 8kHz sampling frequency. After measuring the encoding function, I found that it takes about 46 ms, meaning that on the STM32, I am not able to use Codec2 in real-time - 46 > 40 ms.
Does anyone have experience with this problem and can you tell me how many ms it takes you to encode one frame?
I assume I should get under 40, otherwise it's unusable.

Comment: Are you compiling with optimisation enabled? What clock speed are you using for the MCU? Default projects in CubeIDE typically use a very low clock speed (e.g. 16 MHz) whereas an STM32F4 can typically go over 150 MHz.

Comment: I turned on optimization and it speed up (encoding 40ms frames (320 uint16_t values) takes 15 ms). I am interested if it is possible to further accelerate this. Currently, KISS FFT libraries are used,
Is there for example a compiled CMSIS library that is very effective in terms of speed? Then maybe I could add these libraries to the project instead of KISS? (CPU runs on 160 or 180 MHZ (the maximum))

Comment: ARM have their own [FFT library](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/101004/2310/Fast-Fourier-Transforms-FFTs). I've never used it, but you might hope it is well optimised for ARM.